# Disadvantages of using a function pointer as an UI-Button callback

Tags: c++, user-interface, pointers, sfml

I am currently creating my own GUI-Library based on SFML.
At the moment i am working on a Button. So when creating a button you also have to specify a callback which is a function, executed on the button click.

Now, I'm answering me what the disadvantages are of using just a pointer to a function as a button-callback, because I don't know any popular GUI-Library doing it so simply, too.
If the callback function is a long process, I would execute it in a new thread, but i'm not sure about that in the moment.

So, what would be reasons, not to use such simple solution and especially, what would be a better way?

Comment: As you pointed out, if the function does any non-trivial work it will cause the UI to freeze, which users *hate*.  This is why most GUI libraries have a dedicated thread for the UI, and you are not allowed to do anything "heavy" in that thread.  I think most modern GUI libraries use some kind of event queue system (which can end up making other features easier to implement, such as undo/redo).

Comment: I would suggest specifying callbacks with lambda-closures. This way, thanks to the capture, the closure can interact with anything in the initial environment without the need to forward a `void *` nor rely on OO stuffs like inheritance that introduce a lot of coupling between various parts of the application. And of course, if you are very careful, the closure can launch (or interact with) threads...

Comment: @0x5453 Yeah i would solve that with executing the callback in another thread but it still would be a pointer to a function

Comment: All GUI libraries that I know of _do_ execute the callback on the GUI thread, most of them synchronously but some of them from an event queue. If you want to do heavy work in the callback, you're supposed to write a callback that delegates the work to another thread and returns quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a tricky problem!

Function pointers are simple to implement on the sender side, but they are difficult to use on the receiver side because they they don't have any context.

One issue is that a function pointer cannot point to a member function. That's why you often see (C-style) frameworks pass an arbitrary `void *userData` to their callbacks, so you can cast your `this` pointer and retrieve it in that way. This still needs you to write a static wrapper function to cast the pointer back and call the member function.

A more modern solution would be to use `std::function`. This can contain a regular function pointer, a member function pointer, but also a lambda or a functor.

However, when you add context like this (or in some other way), you quickly run into difficulties with lifetimes. When the receiving class is destroyed before the sender, what is supposed to happen? If you don't do anything, this situation will result in undefined behaviour. A solution is to track on the receiver side to which events the receiver is subscribed, and unbind them before the receiver is destroyed. And this needs to be done in both directions: when the sender is destroyed, it also needs to notify the receiver that it should forget about the sender, otherwise the receiver would later try to unbind an event that no longer exists.

And I haven't even begun to think about multithreading yet...

There are libraries that solve these problems in various ways, for example [`eventpp`](https://github.com/wqking/eventpp) (just found through a web search, this is not an endorsement).

Another one to mention would be the Qt toolkit, which went so far as to write their own small [signals and slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) extension to the C++ language (implemented as a code generator and a pile of macros) to solve this problem in a very ergonomical way.

Answer (score 1):

> what the disadvantages are of using just a pointer to a function as a button-callback

Passing some context argument to that function would come handy.
I mean, the UI may have a lot of buttons performing the same action on various objects. Think maybe of "send message" button next to each nick in a friend list.

So you may want your buttom to pass some context arguments to the call.
But since we're talking C++, this'd better be abstracted as

```
struct IButtonAction
{
    virtual void OnAttached() = 0;
    virtual void OnDetached() = 0;
    virtual void OnClick() = 0;
};
```

And let the client code implement this interface storing whichever `Arg1`, `Arg2`, etc in each instance object.

The button class would call `OnAttached`/`OnDetached` when it begins/ends using the pointer to an instance of this callback interface. These calls must be paired. Client implementation of these methods may perform lifetime management and synchronization with `OnClick`, if required.

`OnClick` method performs the action.

I don't think the button should bother with threads. It's the responsibility of the client code to decide whether to spawn a thread for a lengthy action.